# ReorderableListView with a dynamic background image wrapped in a container as a child in stack

Tags: flutter

how do i put a background image in a container that has a child `ReorderableListView`?
The background image should grow/decrease with the reorderablelist when items are added/removed.

```
    Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: size.height / 5,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                _reorderListWidget(),
                _footer(), // Position(bottom: 0, child: _someWidget());
 ]))
```

in my _reorderListWidget()

```
Widget _reorderListWidget() {
 return Container( // how to do a dynamic height here?
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                          urlPreview!, // image grows with reorderablelist
                          errorListener: () => const Icon(Icons.error),
                        ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: ReorderableListView(
            children: [...]));
}
```

also tried wrapping with `Expanded(child: Column(children: ReorderableListview(....)))` no luck